# Authentication for ServiceStack JavaScript Server Events Client

Tags: javascript, servicestack

I am trying to setup servicestack with ServerEvents.
I have added the plugin for ServerEventsFeature.
I am using the [Javascript server events client](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/JavaScript-Server-Events-Client) and I tried a simple example by doing this on the client **after the user was authenticated**.

```
  var source = new EventSource('http://localhost/ecmapi/event-stream?channel=MyChannel');
  $(source).handleServerEvents({
           handlers: {
                  onConnect: function (subscription) {
                       console.log("connected! welcome " + subscription.displayName);
                  }, 
                  onHeartbeat: function (msg, e) {
                      //console.log("onHeartbeat", msg, e);
                       },
                  showNotification: function (type, e) {
                        console.log("showNotification", type);
                        } 
                  }
           });
```

On the apphost file:

```
            Plugins.Add(new ServerEventsFeature
                   {
                       StreamPath = "/event-stream",           
                       HeartbeatPath = "/event-heartbeat",     
                       UnRegisterPath = "/event-unregister",    
                       SubscribersPath = null, 
                       LimitToAuthenticatedUsers = false, 
                       NotifyChannelOfSubscriptions = false
                   });
```

To send an event to client I am calling:

```
ServerEvents.NotifyChannel("MyChannel", "cmd.showNotification", message);
```

And I successfully receive it on the showNotification function on the client.

However, the subscription.displayName is auto generated and is not related to the currently logged in user. Also, if I set the LimitToAuthenticatedUsers to true then a 401 error is retruned.

My question is, what else is needed so that the javascript server events client can work with the user that is already logged on? I will want to use the ServerEvents.NotifyUserName or ServerEvents.NotifyUserId function instead and also only allow authenticated users to subscribe.

Thanks!

** The request and response headers for auth and EventSource as requested **

**Request auth**

POST http://localhost/ECMAPI/auth.json
HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/json
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://localhost/InterfaceGov/Default.aspx
Accept-Language: en-gb
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)
Host: localhost
Content-Length: 43
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cookie: _ga=GA1.1.2077781525.1452005918; .ASPXANONYMOUS=hOL_MQPsZk5z5t31805S8oazFP0IdbeHKBejAH2x2Ic6hS5070aWW5A-2dklH10qT8IE9pshiAgUkmwN-TfVXjXUhAYVaWKzuOIyCy1nE8VAdETQk1TqB_39gk5ST8cIcvO2KNgB8d5h1f38W8hIzg2; ss-pid=hMBothYg2ETWObMTMJDY; ss-id=x9zxOTH2rFxLo8tO01Nw

**Response auth**

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Vary: Accept
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ServiceStack/4.038 Win32NT/.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Set-Cookie: ss-pid=QjEKGQphtPJZjZJmPtCt; expires=Sun, 11-May-2036 12:18:29 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: ss-id=1yKLtkiTD2NshpiPrffu; path=/; HttpOnly
X-MiniProfiler-Ids: ["1d0459ec1fad4695ac0f3c7fc69cad0a","3f5cd3515e084363b86df1e54633a683","0f54d87508594cba9757660dc664aeef"]
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 11 May 2016 12:18:30 GMT
Content-Length: 17514

**Request EventSource**

GET http://localhost/ecmapi/event-stream?channel=MyChannel HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Origin: http://localhost
Accept-Language: en-GB
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)
Host: localhost
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache

**Response EventSource**

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Cache-Control: private
Vary: Accept
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
WWW-Authenticate: credentials realm="/auth/credentials"
X-Powered-By: ServiceStack/4.038 Win32NT/.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Set-Cookie: ss-pid=c0UQXy4YJNQmVuUiEVfA; expires=Sun, 11-May-2036 12:18:30 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: ss-id=y9e8BbD1na5EoHu8GUug; path=/; HttpOnly
X-MiniProfiler-Ids: ["1d0459ec1fad4695ac0f3c7fc69cad0a","3f5cd3515e084363b86df1e54633a683","0f54d87508594cba9757660dc664aeef","f1584abd58e64a9dac6ceceaa932c47a"]
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 11 May 2016 12:18:30 GMT
Content-Length: 0

Comment: Can you also provide code from your `AppHost` where you add and configure the `ServerEventsFeature` to Plugins?

Comment: @Layoric I have updated my question and included the plugins configuration

Comment: Could you double check that your users in your `IUserAuthRepository` users have the `DisplayName` value populated. If this is null it might be still using the generated value. Also, if you want to restrict to only authenticated users use the `LimitToAuthenticatedUsers` flag in the `ServerEventsFeature`

Comment: @Layoric the user generated by the client is entirely different than the one accessed from the server using GetSession(). Thus, if I set the flag to true then a 401 error is returned. If you see the chat example here https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/Chat then it is also auto generating users.

Comment: I'm not sure where you are calling `GetSession()`. With what you've shown I can't reproduce the problem. I have a simple SSE with auth showing anon and authed usernames are being logged on the client correctly with associated auto user or anon. `LimitToAuthenticatedUsers` Also only logs the `onConnect` when using an authenticated user. [Hopefully this will help narrow down the issue.](https://github.com/Layoric/ServerEventsAuthSimple)

Comment: @NicolasI If `LimitToAuthenticatedUsers` is returning a 401 than you're likely not authenticated. What happens when you call `/auth` from the same App, do you get back 401 as well? This will tell you whether or not you have an authenticated session with ServiceStack.

Comment: @mythz The /auth does not return a 401. As I said I am calling "new EventSource" after the user is logged in.

Comment: Since you're getting a 401 from Server Events stream suggests your not authenticated. Can you post the full HTTP Request and Response for the 401 Response when LimitToAuthenticatedUsers is enabled, you can get it from Chrome Web Inspector or Fiddler.

Comment: That's not the full HTTP Request Headers, it's missing vital info like the Cookies/User Agent, etc.

Comment: @mythz updated the request and response

Comment: There is no cookie being sent in the request, are you using IE with a SSE shim? Does it work in a different browser, e.g. Chrome?

Comment: @mythz Yes thanks. I now tried with chrome and works. Is it not supported on ie9?

Comment: SSE isn't natively supported in IE so it needs to use a shim that's built on XHR. Try registering the CorsFeature plugin.

Comment: @mythz it is already registered.   Plugins.Add(new CorsFeature());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why `/event-stream` returns a **401 Unauthorized** is because your request to `/event-stream` does not contain the necessary Session Cookies which is what establishes an Authenticated request.

This is only an issue in IE since it's the last remaining browser that doesn't have [native support for Server Sent Events](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/6263825-server-sent-events-eventsource) and requires a SSE shim to work where one of its limitations is that it doesn't send Session Cookies.

The [default_ieshim.cshtml](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/Chat/blob/master/src/Chat/default_ieshim.cshtml) in the http://chat.servicestack.net/default_ieshim Live Demo shows how to support Authenticated Requests in IE as well by instead appending the `ss-id` sessionId to the event stream url which you can populate in a Razor page with:

```
var source = new EventSource(
  '/event-stream?channels=@channels&ss-id=@(base.GetSession().Id)&t=' 
  + new Date().getTime());
```

You also need to tell ServiceStack to accept Session Id's in the Url which you can do in your AppHost's `Configure()` with:

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig {
    AllowSessionIdsInHttpParams = true,
});
```

Comment: @NicolasI you should mark the answer off as completed if it helped

Comment: just a quick question please. we have an apache server that is acting as a reverse proxy. when calling event-stream after login the request is fine (http://devserver/ecmapi/evernt-stream). However, when the event-heartbeat is called it is not returned using the correct reverse proxy url (http://devserver:81/ecmapi/evernt-stream). the port is added and an 403 Invalid User Address is returned.

Comment: sorry the heartbeat is called on devserver:81/ecmapi/event-heartbeat

Comment: @NicolasI please ask a new question for new questions. If you want it to use a different URL to the incoming Request Url you need to explicitly specify it with Config.WebHostUrl.

Comment: i think something has to do with the heartbeat url. I am using the default. Is this a problem of eventsource? when adding the ServerEventsFeature plugin  the HeartbeatPath = "/event-heartbeat"

Comment: is heartbeat required?

Comment: @NicolasI Yes it is.

Comment: @can you please clarify what it's purpose is? because although we receive the 403 errors the server is able to send messages to the clients and the clients received them.

Comment: Its a heartbeat message to tell the server to keep the connection alive and not close it.